Issue: Jupyter Notebook Default Directory Not Updating

Environment Setup:

Jupyter Notebook is installed under a virtual environment ana-env.
By default, Jupyter Notebook starts in C:\Users\<username>.


Steps Taken to Change Startup Directory:

I located the config file:
C:\Users<username>\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py
I updated the configuration to set the default directory:
c.ServerApp.root_dir = 'd:\\'
Saved the changes and restarted Jupyter Notebook.


Observed Behavior:

Despite modifying the config file, Jupyter Notebook still starts in the default directory C:\Users\<username>
The output message confirms this:
[I ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\<username>


Command-Line Launch:

When I run the command jupyter notebook --notebook-dir="d:\\" the notebook successfully starts in D:\.


Warnings in Output:

I also noticed warnings during startup:
[W ServerApp] A _jupyter_server_extension_points function was not found...



Questions:

Why is the c.ServerApp.root_dir setting in the config file not taking effect?
Are the startup warnings and skipped server messages related to this behavior?
What steps can I take to ensure Jupyter Notebook uses the updated startup directory from the config file?


What is the version of Jupyter Notebook?

And with the single slash in the other direction (/ instead of \)  for the path ? if not maybe try double quotation mark instead of ' . The notebooks are not on the cloud?
